# Replace value from forloop in a text and concatenate results

Tags: awk, sed

I have an arithmetic `set Z=2;6;11;165;95;59;131` etc. I want to replace `Z` in following text and concatenate results in a single file:

```
HSS-ServiceType=vpbxdZ
HSS-ServiceTrigger=Z0401
    no HSS-SptGroup=1
    no HSS-SptGroup=2
commit -s
    up
HSS-ServiceTrigger=Z0471
    no HSS-SptGroup=1
    no HSS-SptGroup=2
commit -s
    up
no HSS-ServiceProfile=vpbxdZs1
commit -s
no HSS-ServiceTrigger=Z0401
commit -s
no HSS-ServiceTrigger=Z0471
commit -s
up
no HSS-ServiceType=vpbxdZ
commit -s
```

I've tried with `awk` like below

```
awk 'BEGIN { for(Z=2;6;11;165;95;59;131) print 
/HSS-ServiceType=vpbxdZ
/HSS-ServiceTrigger=Z0401
/   no HSS-SptGroup=1
/   no HSS-SptGroup=2
/commit -s
    up
/HSS-ServiceTrigger=Z0471
/   no HSS-SptGroup=1
/   no HSS-SptGroup=2
/commit -s
/   up
/no HSS-ServiceProfile=vpbxdZs1
/commit -s
/no HSS-ServiceTrigger=Z0401
/commit -s
/no HSS-ServiceTrigger=Z0471
/commit -s
/up
/no HSS-ServiceType=vpbxdZ
/commit -s }' test1.txt
```

but it fails with error

```
"^ unterminated regexp":
```

The  desired output will be something like this:

```
HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd2
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=20401
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=20471
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    no HSS-ServiceProfile=vpbxd2s1
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=20401
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=20471
    commit -s
    up
no HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd2
commit -s

HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd6
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=60401
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=60471
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    no HSS-ServiceProfile=vpbxd6s1
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=60401
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=60471
    commit -s
    up
no HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd6
commit -s

HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd11
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=110401
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=110471
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    no HSS-ServiceProfile=vpbxd11s1
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=110401
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=110471
    commit -s
    up
no HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd11
commit -s

HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd165
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=1650401
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=1650471
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    no HSS-ServiceProfile=vpbxd165s1
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=1650401
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=1650471
    commit -s
    up
no HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd165
commit -s

HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd95
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=950401
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    HSS-ServiceTrigger=950471
        no HSS-SptGroup=1
        no HSS-SptGroup=2
    commit -s
        up
    no HSS-ServiceProfile=vpbxd95s1
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=950401
    commit -s
    no HSS-ServiceTrigger=950471
    commit -s
    up
no HSS-ServiceType=vpbxd95
commit -s
```

i.e. 7 copies of the original file, where for each copy the `Z` is replaced by a different value according to the `for` loop statement in my original attempt.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The `awk` error message is rather straightforward, as `/ ... /` is the `awk` syntax for specifying regular expressions, and you have an odd number of those in an unquoted string. Perhaps you should provide not only example input, but also desired output in your question so that contributors can better understand what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i've never seen this syntax either: `for(Z=2;6;11;165;95;59;131)`. it also throws a syntax error for me...

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you want to replace the first occurence of `Z` with `2`, the second with `6`, the third with `11` etc.?

Answer (score 3):

from what I guess, you want to change Z value in a sample file.

```
for z in 2 6 11 165 95 59 131
do 
   sed -e "s/=Z/=$z/" -e "s/dZ/d$z/" sample.txt
done > result.txt
```

where

- `sample.txt` is your starting file
- `-e "s/=Z/=$z/"` and `-e "s/dZ/d$z/"` are the actual search and replace order.

Comment: @AdminBee !? you copy paste my code and end with 7 files ?

Comment: too bad, changing consecutive `Z` with different value is much more challenging.

Comment: Yeah I agree - I actually had a nice one prepared ... ;)

Comment: Oh, is that so ? I'll vote to reopen then.

Comment: Nah, it's ok; it doesn't make sense to post a solution to a problem "more challening than but different from what the OP actually asked"; but thanks for the offer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can for loop  from within awk itself.

```
Z="2;6;11;165;95;59;131" \
awk '
  BEGIN { I = ENVIRON["Z"] }
  { f = f $0 ORS }
  END {
    N = split(I, a, ";")
    for (i=1; i<=N; i++) {
      t = f
      gsub(/dZ/, "d" a[i], t)
      gsub(/=Z/, "=" a[i], t)
      print t
    }
  }
' file.txt
```

We are storing the indices in the environment var Z.

We split this on semicolon abd store the iterable indices in the array a.

We slurp the whole file in the var f.

Finally we iterate over the indices and substitute the regex dZ and =Z with the iterable. Print the var. Repeat for other in dices.

Comment: Thank you very much Rakesh & all you guys! It worked :).

Thank you also for the explanations. very very useful! 
See you on the road, Alex

Comment: @AlexeiMarcovici if you found any of the answers particularly useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.